# How to obtain a list of objects inside another object using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Using reflection I can obtain the object properties and values for all Data Types and the objects inside this object. But if the object contains a List of other objects I am having trouble in getting the objects in the list. The list can contain any type of object.

```
private static void SaveObj(object obj) {
   foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) {
       if (prop.PropertyType.Namespace == "Entities") { //It is an object
           object obL = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
           SaveObj(obj);
       }
       else if (prop.PropertyType.Name == "List`1") { //This is a list of objects
           object obP = prop.GetValue(obj); 
           //obP has the list of objects, I can see the list in debug mode.
           List<object> obL = (List<object>)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
           //This line returns an exception!!
       }
       else {
           columns += prop.Name.ToLower() + ", ";
           values[i] = prop.GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
       }
       ... // the code continues ...
   }
}
```

The exception message returned is:
"It is not possible to convert an object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entities.OrderItem]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'."

Interesting is that I can see all the objects and its contents in degug mode. In Immediate Window I can print the content of the variable obP with all the objects in the list, but how to read them?

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try casting it to `IEnumerable` and then use `.Cast<object>().ToList()` Like this:

```
IEnumerable obL = prop.GetValue(obj, null) as IEnumerable;
List<object> list = obL.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you Anton for your prompt help.

Comment: @MarceloTropia I'm glad it worked. Please consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. That indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sins a `List` implements the `ICollection` interface, you could, instead of attempting to cast the returned value to a `List<object>`, do something like:

```
ICollection collection = (prop.GetValue(obj, null) as ICollection);

if (collection != null)
{
    object[] array = new object[collection.Count];

    collection.CopyTo(array, 0);

    //if you need a list just create a new one and pass in the array: new List<object>(array);
}
```

As a side note, wouldn't your:

```
if (prop.PropertyType.Namespace == "Entities")
{
    object obL = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
    SaveObj(obj);
}
```

just cause a infinite loop, which will lead to a `StackOverflow`/`OutOfMemory` exception, might want to change it to `SaveObj(obL);` if that was the intended behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your help Vincent. In fact I didn't try your suggestion. I followed Anton's suggestion and it worked perfectly. Regarding the "loop", yes you are right. My intention  is a recursive call and the correct is "SaveObj(obL)".